# ring server messages not traversing ring

Tags: process, erlang, server

I've almost implemented the well-known ring server, however the messages do not seem to be traversing the ring - here's my code:

```
module(ring).
-import(lists,[duplicate/2,append/1,zip/2,nthtail/2,nth/2,reverse/1]).
-export([start/3,server/0]).



start(M,N,Msg)->
    start(M,N,[],Msg).

start(0,0,_,_)->
    ok;
start(M,0,PList,Msg)->
    nth(1,PList)!nthtail(1,reverse(zip(append(duplicate(M,PList)),duplicate(M*length(PList),Msg))));
start(M,N,PList,Msg)->
    start(M,N-1,[spawn(ring, server, [])|PList],Msg).

server()-> 
    receive
        []->
            ok;
        [{Pid,Msg}|T]->
            io:format("~p,~p~n",[self(),Msg]),
            Pid!T;
        terminate->
            true
    end.
```

it returns the following when executed:

```
2> ring:start(3,3,"hello").
<0.42.0>,"hello"
<0.41.0>,"hello"
[{<0.41.0>,"hello"},
 {<0.42.0>,"hello"},
 {<0.40.0>,"hello"},
 {<0.41.0>,"hello"},
 {<0.42.0>,"hello"},
 {<0.40.0>,"hello"},
 {<0.41.0>,"hello"},
 {<0.42.0>,"hello"}]
```

May I ask where I am going wrong here? I've checked the zipped process list, and it seems as if it should work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your processes are terminating, not looping (and there is never a condition under which they will receive `'terminate'`). To solve the termination issue, have them `spawn_link` instead of just `spawn` so that when the first one dies, they all die.

It is good to kick things off by messaging yourself, to make sure you're not stripping the first message entirely.

```
-module(ring).
-import(lists,[duplicate/2,append/1,zip/2,nthtail/2,nth/2,reverse/1]).
-export([start/3,server/0]).

start(M, N, Msg)->
    Scroll = start(M, N, [], Msg),
    self() ! Scroll.

start(0, 0, _, _)->
    ok;
start(M, 0, PList, Msg)->
    nth(1, PList) ! nthtail(1, reverse(zip(append(duplicate(M, PList)),
    duplicate(M * length(PList), Msg))));
start(M, N, PList, Msg)->
    start(M, N - 1, [spawn_link(ring, server, []) | PList], Msg).

server()->
    receive
        []->
            ok;
        [{Pid, Msg} | T]->
            io:format("~p,~p~n", [self(), Msg]),
            Pid ! T,
            server()
    end.
```

This produces:

```
1> c(ring).
{ok,ring}
2> ring:start(3,3,"raar!").
<0.42.0>,"raar!"
<0.41.0>,"raar!"
[{<0.41.0>,"raar!"},
 {<0.42.0>,"raar!"},
 {<0.40.0>,"raar!"},
 {<0.41.0>,"raar!"},
 {<0.42.0>,"raar!"},
 {<0.40.0>,"raar!"},
 {<0.41.0>,"raar!"},
 {<0.42.0>,"raar!"}]
<0.42.0>,"raar!"
<0.40.0>,"raar!"
<0.41.0>,"raar!"
<0.42.0>,"raar!"
<0.40.0>,"raar!"
<0.41.0>,"raar!"
```

As expected. Note that I'm calling `server()` again on receipt of a message. When the empty list is received they all die because they are linked. No mess.

Some spacing for readability would have been a little more polite. Erlangers usually aren't so leet that we want to plow through a solid mass of characters -- and this actually causes errors with a few operators in some edge cases (like in map syntax). Also, using imported functions is a little less clear. I know is gums up the code with all that namespace business, but its a lifesaver when you start writing larger programs (there are a lot of list operations in the `erlang` module -- so some of this importing is unnecessary anyway http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#hd-1).

Comment: Thanks very much - I wan't aware of the spawn_link/3 function, I'll look into that - I also can see how spacing improves readability here.

Comment: @Bracket Just write some more programs and you'll get the hang of things. Going back to re-read the original things you wrote (once you forgot the details of all the clever stuff you buried in each long, complex line) will give you a good idea where the balance between compact syntax and readability lies in this language. Lucky for us, the basic language idioms become obvious fairly quick. The longer, slower learning curve is OTP and what it *means* (instead of what this or that isolated component *does*).

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 mistakes here, the main one is that you do not recursively recall server after printing the message.

The second one is that you should not remove the head of your list when you build the first message, otherwise you will have only m*n - 1 messages passed.

this code works, but it leaves all the processes active, you should enhance it to kill all processes at the end of the "ring":

```
-module(ring).
-import(lists,[duplicate/2,append/1,zip/2,nthtail/2,nth/2,reverse/1]).
-export([start/3,server/0]).

start(M,N,Msg)->
    start(M,N,[],Msg).

start(0,0,_,_)->
    ok;
start(M,0,PList,Msg)->
    nth(1,PList)!reverse(zip(append(duplicate(M,PList)),duplicate(M*length(PList),Msg)));
start(M,N,PList,Msg)->
    start(M,N-1,[spawn(ring, server, [])|PList],Msg).

server()-> 
    receive
        []->
            ok;
        [{Pid,Msg}|T]->
            io:format("In Server ~p,~p~n",[self(),Msg]),
            Pid!T,
            server();
        terminate->
            true
    end.
```

On my side, I don't use import, I find it more explicit when I have lists:reverse..., You can use hd/1 to get the first element of a list, and you could use list comprehension to generate your list of {Pid,Msg}

Comment: Wow. I think we clicked "submit" at nearly the same moment.

Comment: Its funny (almost uncanny) how often we basically give the same answer, at the same time. Even the same structure. Anyway, +1 for being right and beating me to the punch by 20 seconds or so. :-)

Comment: Thanks very much - such a noob mistake! About 2), I don't fully understand why I need to keep the head - I thought the first process only needs sender info?

Comment: Thanks also for the hd/1 ref! Wasn't aware of that.

Comment: When you remove the head, there are m*n messages exchanged, but the first one is from the shell to the first process in the ring, so this one is not really part of the ring, as I said it is minor, and maybe subject to interpretation of the goal...